# Flex binding two variables

Tags: flash, apache-flex, data-binding

I don't know Flex/Flash, but I have a legacy code and it forces me to look for an answer. Help me please.

I have got controller and presenter classes. Controller can load some configurations, I added boolean variable isConfigurationLoaded here and now I want to bind this variable in controller with same variable in presenter. How I can do it?

I read about BindingUtils, but a lot of samples have a parts of mxml files and It scares me a little bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to declare your variable as Bindable in your controller so the BindingUtils will get events once it changes:

```
[Bindable]
public var isConfigurationLoaded:Boolean;
```

Then set up the binding in your presenter:

```
// use weak references so it will be garbage collected
BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, "isConfigurationLoaded", myControllerReference, "isConfigurationLoaded", false, true);

public function set isConfigurationLoaded(value:Boolean):void
{
    trace("isConfigurationLoaded in the controller has changed to " + value);
    _isConfigurationLoaded = value;
}

public function get isConfigurationLoaded():Boolean
{
    return _isConfigurationLoaded;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to create a getter / setter for your variable, you can bind the variable to a function call in your presenter:

```
// use weak references so it will be garbage collected
BindingUtils.bindSetter(onisConficurationLoaded, myControllerReference, "isConfigurationLoaded", false, true); 

private function onisConficurationLoaded(value:String):void
{
    trace("isConfigurationLoaded in the controller has changed to " + value);
    isConficurationLoaded = value;
}
```

BindingUtils return a ChangeWatcher instance, you can store it and unwatch the property if needed:

```
// watch
var changeWatcher:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(onisConficurationLoaded, myControllerReference, "isConfigurationLoaded");

// unwatch
changeWatcher.unwatch();
```